# Windows C++ Eclipse MinGW link both dynamic and static library

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I am new to C++ programming. There are 2 libraries in my program, one needs to be linked dynamically, and the other needs to be linked statically, how can I set this up in Eclipse? I am using
Eclipse CDT + MinGW + Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're after here.

Most of static vs. dynamic is in the library itself, not how you link to it. You can have a static library, which is basically just a collection of object files, stuffed together into a single file, with a directory to tell what parts were originally which files.

You can also have a DLL. When you create a DLL, the linker will normally also create a link library for that DLL. This library basically just contains stubs -- enough information so the linker can insert a link to the DLL into another DLL or executable.

When you use a DLL, you basically have three options for how to use it:

1. The most common case: the DLL will be loaded as the parent executable is loaded.
2. delayload: doesn't load that DLL until/unless you actually use a function from it (handy if you have, for example, a special DLL that's only used under, say, Windows Vista or newer).
3. Explicit dynamic linking. Here, you don't tell the linker about the DLL or an associated library at all. You call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to load the library, and get a callable function address.

Comment: I have a abc.dll library, and I wish to link it statically. But in my MinGW Linker, I already have following options "g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++". I am wondering how can I set it up to link abc.dll statically. Thank you.

Comment: Normally just something like: `g++ whatever.cpp -L. -lyour_dll`

Comment: By "link statically" did you mean you wanted the library to be embedded in your executable so that you don't need to ship it as a separate file?  Because you can't do that with a DLL.